# I can't commit or push, this is what I got when I checked the status

Tags: git

Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 4 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
(use "git pull" to update your local branch)

All conflicts fixed but you are still merging.
(use "git commit" to conclude merge)

Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add/rm ..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git restore ..." to discard changes in working directory)
deleted:    READme.md
modified:   ../README.md

Untracked files:
(use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)
up_to_date

Comment: That’s great and all but what are the error messages you see?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: it shows this when ever I want to commit :

Comment: fatal: Unable to create '/root/alx-pre_course/.git/index.lock': File exists.                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                
Another git process seems to be running in this repository,